# X509Certificate.Export Method

Tags: c#

I try export cert .pfx :

```
string certPath = "D:\\cert.pfx";
cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "pass");

byte[] certData = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx,"pass"); /// **error in this line** 

X509Certificate newCert = new X509Certificate(certData,"pass");
```

But it finish with this error :

**Key not valid for use in specified state.**

Can somebody help me ??  Any solution as export certificate from store ??

Answer (score 8):

I think that you were unable to export the private key because the constructor you have used to create the certificate `X509Certificate2(filePath, password)` does not mark the resulting certificate as exportable. I suggest to use one of the overloaded constructors that allows you to specify the exportable flag - X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable, for example 
`X509Certificate2(filePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)`.

Details on available [constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.x509certificate2.aspx) for the X509Certificate2 and other X509KeyStorageFlags on MSDN Library.

Also you should check the X509Certificate2.HasPrivateKey property to make sure that you have a private key associated with the certificate.

Comment: BTW - this answer is correct. Poster should have marked it as such

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the certificate is Exportable?

Look [at this to help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/af053e77-f219-4467-b674-93168b660551).

EDIT:

Have a [look at this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=31773475&threadid=31773475), seems this guy had a very similar problem and had it solved.

Comment: I don't know any C#, but he seems to be loading the certificate from a PKCS#12 file, not from a smartcard, so I don't think being exportable is an issue here...

Comment: @lapo, a Smartcard is not the only method for working with .PFX, for instance code signing in .NET is done with PFX files, but I may have the situation confused with something else.

Answer (score 0):

For those that doesn't solved with these answers, here's my solution:

Instead saving as pfx

```
byte[] certData = certificado.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "pass");
```

try to save as another content type, mine was "Cert"

```
byte[] certData = certificado.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, "pass");
```